# how to modify date time column format in to minute interval in list form "Sharepoint online"

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-list

Using If Else statement I'm comparing "expire date time" column with a current date before submitting the `newform.aspx`,

but if I put the expire date time at 8am with the condition (current date<=8am) using "`PreSaveAction`" function, newform is saving the list values till 7:59 am in stead till 8am (since I'm using <=8am) loosing one minute here. I want to save the values until 8am.

how should I make this work? any help, please.

Comment: Where is the IF statement? In JavaScript code? In a Calculated Column? In a Workflow?

Comment: Depending on how you are testing, it's unlikely that you will ever hit exactly 8:00 AM. SharePoint DateTime is represented internally as a number (42,763.9461689815 for example with 42763 days since day "0" plus a fraction of a day the .946...) put you a fraction of a second before or after 8:00 AM.   8:00AM is 8/24ths of a day, so 0.33333333333333. So today at 8:00AM was 43128.3333333333. I use this numeric aspect of dates to create (pseudo) random numbers in a calculated column: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2016/11/creating-random-numbers-in-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to round down to the nearest minute, you could use this in a Calculated column (assuming your column is "Created"):

```
=DATE(YEAR([Created]),MONTH([Created]),DAY([Created]))+TIME(HOUR([Created]),MINUTE([Created]),0)
```

It sets the second to zero.

Comment: Hi mike, I'm not using calculated column, it is date time (expire date time) type manually enters in another list, I'm just retrieving it from another list and assigning it in another list that I wanted to check that expire date column with current date whether it is past the dead line or not,

Comment: so everything is working fine with the "PreSaveAction" function it is checking the expire date time with current date time before saving the item,. only issue if I put the expire date with time 8am (if else statement)it is taking until 7:59 loosing one  minute here. I want it to be worked as it has 8am expire date. if any solution would be greatly appreciable. thanks so much

Comment: and it is javascript